# openapi-generator producing bad api docs for typescript

Tags: typescript, openapi-generator

I'm running the following command to produce an auto-generated api from openapi-generator (v6.0.1 - stable)

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i app.json -g typescript -o src/main/api
```

The json file is valid. I ran `openapi-generator-cli validate -i app.json` to make sure of it.

The command executes successfully but when I attempt to use one of the api endpoints according to the auto-generated docs, I see that the import statements/initial configuration for the API I should be using are missing key information:

```js
import {  } from '';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const configuration = .createConfiguration();
const apiInstance = new .AuthApi(configuration);
```

Looking at Datadog's node.js api client I think it should look something like this

```
import { client, v1 } from '@datadog/datadog-api-client';

const configuration = client.createConfiguration();
const apiInstance = new v1.MonitorsApi(configuration);
```

What am I missing for the generator to not also give my api correct imports?

EDIT:
Example json file:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.2",
    "info": {
        "title": "NinjaAPI",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": ""
    },
    "paths": {
        "/api/auth/cli/pickup/{pickup_key}/": {
            "get": {
                "operationId": "users_api_cli_pickup",
                "summary": "Cli Pickup",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "path",
                        "name": "pickup_key",
                        "schema": {
                            "title": "Pickup Key",
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "uuid"
                        },
                        "required": true
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/PickupResponse"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "tags": [
                    "auth"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "PickupResponse": {
                "title": "PickupResponse",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "success": {
                        "title": "Success",
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "jwt": {
                        "title": "Jwt",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "success"
                ]
            }
        },
        "securitySchemes": {
            "UserJWTBearerAuth": {
                "type": "http",
                "scheme": "bearer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What version of the OpenAPI Generator do you use? 2) Can you post your `app.json` file (or a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so that others can reproduce the issue? It's possible that the file has e.g. OpenAPI syntax errors that the validator couldn't catch.

Comment: @Helen Added 1 and 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like openapi-generator requires `moduleName` and `projectName` to be set for documentation files to include correct code.

These could set via config file (e.g. `config.json`):

```
{
  "moduleName": "NinjaAPI",
  "projectName": "@ninja/api-client"
}
```

and passed to openapi-generator:

`openapi-generator-cli generate -i app.json -g typescript -o src/main/api -c config.json`